# How to Add User in Liferay by calling Json Web service with Custom User Object?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am getting

> No JSON web service action associated with path /user/add-user and
>   method POST for /

Error while adding New User in Liferay with Webservice Rest client.

I have created AddUserDTO pojo with following fields:

```
private long companyId;
private boolean autoPassword;
private String password1;
private String password2;
private boolean autoScreenName;
private String screenName;
private String emailAddress;
private long facebookId;
private String openId;
private Locale locale;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String middleName;
private int prefixId;
private int suffixId;
private boolean male;
private int birthdayMonth;
private int birthdayDay;
private int birthdayYear;
private String jobTitle;
private Long [] groupIds;
private Long [] organizationIds;
private Long [] roleIds;
private Long [] userGroupIds;
private boolean sendEmail;
```

and passing it over http

```
public HttpRequest httpRequest() throws UKePortalException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(getENDPOINT());
        System.out.println("Endpoint :"+sb);
        if (Method.GET.equals(getMETHOD())) {
            sb.append(getParams());
            return new HttpGet(sb.toString());
        } else if (Method.POST.equals(getMETHOD())) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(sb.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(getEntities());
            System.out.println("httpPost :"+httpPost+" : "+httpPost.toString());
            return httpPost;
        }
        throw new UKePortalException("No METHOD defined");
    }

private HttpEntity getEntities() throws UKePortalException {
    List<Field> fields = getAllFields(this.getClass());
    MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    multipartEntityBuilder.setCharset(Charset.defaultCharset());
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Object value = getValue(this, field.getName());

        String text = String.valueOf(value);
        if (value instanceof File) {
            multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(field.getName(), (File) value);
        } else if (!(value instanceof String)) {
            text = (new Gson()).toJson(value);
            multipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody(field.getName(), text, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        } else {
            multipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody(field.getName(), text, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
    }
    return multipartEntityBuilder.build();
}
```

By calling httpRequest() method. My ENDPOINT is set to "/api/jsonws/user/add-user"

I am wondering if I miss anything while calling add user. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing some parameters to be passed. Probably last argument serviceContext

Comment: I tried with servicecontext as well but still same error.

Comment: No user authentication details in request header!!

Comment: @suyash : Please log the entire request body which will give you clear idea. Such kind of error you see when you have not passed all required parameters to web-service.